# Como inserir dados vindos de um formulário no Banco de dados [PDOstatment - CRUD]

Tags: php, sql, crud

Estou fazendo uma `CRUD` simples para inserção de dados obtidos a partir de um formulário. Fiz a função mas a mesma não funciona e não apresenta nenhum erro. Acredito que seja pelo fato de as informações provenientes do `form` não estarem chegando via `$_POST`.

Gostaria de saber o que está faltando e como eu posso fazer essa ligação, de acordo com o código que estou fazendo abaixo!

**OBS:** Eu consigo ter conexão com o banco de dados!

Formulário:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="PT-BR">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="../../controllers/UserController.php" method="post" name="formLogin">
        <label>E-mail</label>
        <div class="email">
            <input type="text" name="user[email]" required>
        </div>  

        <!--INSERIR A CONFIRMAÇÃO DE E-MAIL-->

        <label>Password</label>
        <div class="password">
            <input type="password" name="user[password]" required>
        </div>  
        <!--INSERIR A CONFIRMAÇÃO DE SENHA-->

        <label>Nível de Acesso</label>
        <div class="">  
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="user[level]" value="1">
                Gerente
            </label>
            <label>         
                <input type="radio" name="user[level]" value="2">
                Membro
            </label>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="user[type]" value="1">
                Nível 1
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="user[type]" value="2">
                Nível 2
            </label>
        </div>  

        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="insert">

        <div class="submit">
            <input type="submit" name="submit">
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Model User.php

```
 <?php
require_once(__DIR__."../../helpers/Connection.php");

class User {
    public $id;
    public $email;
    public $password;
    public $level;
    public $type;

    public function __construct($attributes) {
        $this->id = isset($attributes['id']) ? $attributes['id'] : null;
        $this->email = $attributes['email'];
        $this->password = $attributes['password'];
        $this->level = $attributes['level'];
        $this->type = $attributes['type'];
    }

    public function insert(){
        $connect = Connection::connect();
        $stm = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO user(email, password, level, type) VALUES (':email', ':password', ':level', ':type')");
        $stm = bindValue(":email", $this->email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stm = bindValue(":password", $this->password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stm = bindValue(":level", $this->level, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stm = bindValue(":type", $this->type, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        return $stm->execute();

    }
}
?>
```

UserController.php

```
<?php
require_once("../models/Users.php");
/**
* 
*/
class UserController {

    public static function insert(){
        $user = new User($_POST["user"]);
        $user->insert();

    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Não vai aspa simples nos placeholders. Revise os `name`s dos inputs também

Comment: porquê estás a usar estrutura mvc ? a requisição não está sequer a passar do controller.

Comment: Ainda estou aprendendo, Edilson. Por isso estou perguntando o que tem de errado...

Comment: @rray quais placeholders? Só conheço placeholders no html e não tem nenhum ali... E revisar o name dos inputs de que forma? Porque, pelo que entendi, era isso se comunicava com o php

Comment: Placeholders são 'marcações' que vc coloca para trocar eles por valores. `VALUES (':email', ':password', ':level', ':type')` não vai aspas simples em todos eles `:email`, `:password` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Os placeholders (:email, :password) não precisam de aspas, eles servem de substitutos pelos valores que você irá passar.

```
<?php
    require_once(__DIR__."../../helpers/Connection.php");

    class User {
        public $id;
        public $email;
        public $password;
        public $level;
        public $type;

        public function __construct($attributes) {
            $this->id = isset($attributes['id']) ? $attributes['id'] : null;
            $this->email = $attributes['email'];
            $this->password = $attributes['password'];
            $this->level = $attributes['level'];
            $this->type = $attributes['type'];
        }

        public function insert(){
            $connect = Connection::connect();
            $stm = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO user(email, password, level, type) VALUES (:email, :password, :level, :type)");
            $stm = bindValue(":email", $this->email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stm = bindValue(":password", $this->password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stm = bindValue(":level", $this->level, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stm = bindValue(":type", $this->type, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            return $stm->execute();

        }
    }
    ?>
```